# How to avoid passing currentTime about in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, time, sprite-kit

I have discovered in developing my app that some of my nodes need access to the currentTime as passed to the update method in  order to implement business logic.

It seems messy to constantly pass this as a parameter to all of the initialisers and methods that might need it.

I am wondering what solutions other developers might have had to this problem (are there any standard patterns). Accessing the system time is an option, but there is probably some overhead, and it will vary each time it is called.

Maybe a global could be used, but I am wondering if there could be any threading issues or issues using it in a closure.

Options?

Comment: Are you talking about passing time to a subclass or being used within the GameScene?

Comment: All those methods can be overwritten so why not doing that and avoid passing the same parameter all the time?

Comment: So, for example, I have a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` (in fact, several) that has behaviour based its age, so I need to pass the current time to the constructor when it is created (so the class can remember when it was created) and then again to various methods when they are called from `update` in the scene (so it knows how old it is). It is a pain because, depending on design decisions, a method may or may not need the time. So I need to change the method signature if time becomes a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose you can create some sort of global variable, e.g.:

```
static var _currentTime: CFTimeInterval = 0
```

And then in your update func you can assign the current time to that variable:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    _currentTime = currentTime
}
```

As long as you declare the global variable outside of any scope you should be able to access it from everywhere in your game.

Answer (score 1):

I started off with the global variable approach, which is the obvious answer and an up-voted one. It is simple, but I wasn't really happy with it. In the end, I hit upon the following approach which seems cleaner.

I run all of my custom timed actions now either directly or indirectly from action blocks run from `SKAction.runBlock` or `SKAction.customActionWithDuration`.

If I want to know the time from a particular event, I insert an action as follows in my list of actions:

```
SKAction.customActionWithDuration(level.duration, actionBlock : {(node, elapsedTime) in
    self.elapsedTime = elapsedTime
})
```

If I need other things to happen in parallel with this timer, I just use an `SKAction.group` to run everything at the same time.

The only slight issue is that the block refers to `self`, which I never like as it makes it reliant on the creator of the action being the node, but you could always cast `node` to the actual node type and use that.

UPDATE:

I discovered that the execution of actions in SpriteKit is not all that reliable, in terms of when they actually start and finish. It appears there is some drift possible - perhaps the start of an action can be delayed by the framework, or perhaps the drift occurs during the sequence. In the former case, the clock might not start ticking when you think it does. For a constant reference time, it is probably therefore better to use the global variable approach.

Answer (score 1):

In an app I'm currently working on I've implemented the following:

```
protocol Updatable {
    func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
}
```

`Updatable` is to be implemented by any nodes you want to be updated according to the current time.

You then need a custom `SKScene`, which will update any child nodes which conform to `Updatable`. For Swift 2:

```
class MyScene: SKScene {
    public override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        super.update(currentTime)

        for case let child as Updateable in children {
            child.update(currentTime)
        }
    }
}
```

Or, for Swift 1 use:

```
for child in children {
    if let updateableNode = child as? Updateable {
        updateableNode.update(currentTime)
    }
}
```

Now that's done you just need to make sure any of your `SKScene` subclasses are subclasses of `MyScene`.